# How to read in a string of Numbers into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am working on a programming assignment in which we are making our own BigNum class. One of the constructors needs to be set up so that it can take a number from a string (i.e. 342567) and reads it into an array. However if the number were 0000000342567 it would have to be able to skip over the 0s and just read 342567.

Where is what i have so far but am lost on trimming the 0s

```
BigNum::BigNum(const char strin[])
{
    size_t size = strlen(strin);
    positive = true;
    capacity = size;
    digits = new size_t[capacity];
    used=0;

    while(used<size)
    {
        if(strin[size - used -1] =='-')
        {
            positive = false;
            size --;
        }
        else if(strin[size - used -1] =='+')
        {
            size --;
        }
        else
        {
            digits[used] = strin[size - used -1] - '0';
            used++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the assignment description if it helps 
http://csel.cs.colorado.edu/%7Eekwhite/CSCI2270Fall2011/hw2/Homework2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this just before your while loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (strin[i] >= '1' && strin[i] <= '9')
    {
        used = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

This way, your while loop begins reading the string only from the index where the number actually begins, skipping over all leading 0s.

This should handle the leading sign as well:

```
BigNum::BigNum(const char strin[])
{
    size_t size = strlen(strin);
    positive = true;        
    used=0;

    if (strin[0] == '+' || strin[0] == '-')
    {
        //set positive or negative
        used++;
    }
    while (used < size)
    {
        if (strin[used] != '0')     
            break;

        used++; //used will only increment if above if condition failed.
    }

    int digitIndex = 0;
    digits = new size_t[size-used]; //create digits array here so it isn't larger than needed

    while(used<size)
    {        
         digits[digitIndex++] = strin[used++];      
    }
}
```

Comment: does this also take into account if the number starts with + or -. since i check it in the while loop

Comment: @Sean: You shouldn't actually check for the sign in the while loop, I told you why in my answer below.

Comment: is the new while loop in the above code testing for the leading zeros

Comment: the first if condition is for the case where there is a sign. The first while is for leading zeroes. Once you've consumed the sign and the leading zeroes, create your digits array then so its not larger than required. Then iterate through all the digits in the strin array.

Comment: if i wanted to read the remaining numbers in backward (i.e. the number 345 is actual in the array like [5,4,3] what should the index be for each number

Comment: in that case, just iterate the last while loop backwards so the condition is: `while (size >=used)` and `digits[digitIndex++] = strin[--size]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint:

Write a separate loop at the beginning that skips over all the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add another `while` loop before the one you have.

But just some other hints:

You can't change the sign of the number at any digit, the sign depends only on the very first charachter. So if you had a string like `-2345`, that'll be ok, but if you had something other like: `234-88` then this should be invalid, what will you do with this then?

Also the `digits` array shouldn't really be equal to `size`, but rather should drop the sign digit if it did exist, so how will you deal with `capacity`?

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: but i need to have the sign check in there. i can see it should be in the while loop but am confused how the digits array is gonna change as you say. should i have a if statement that makes a new capacity and size

Comment: `capacity` should be equal to `size` at the very beginning, then, with an `if` statement that checks the first digit, you should change the `capacity` and also the `positive` (which I suppose should be `sign`), after that comes memory allocation, and then the `while` loop that skips zeros, and then the other `while` loop that only reads digits without any `if` statements, because there is a relationship between every X digit and it's associated 'X' character.